# Using Caffe pretrained model for FCN-Image-Segmentation

Tags: python-3.x, caffe, image-segmentation

I am trying to compile the following model: http://manutdzou.github.io/2016/12/27/FCN-segmentation.html

but I got the error:

> KeyError: 'fc6_my'

When I look to: `solver.net.params.keys()`, I get the output as: `odict_keys([ ])`

I don't know why it is giving `no keys for the object: solver.net.params`.